# AngularJS deferred.reject not working but $q.reject working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I am confused between Angular JS deferred and $q. I found this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24443733/angulars-q-reject-vs-deferred-reject) that explains the difference between `$q.defer()` and `$q`.It explains

> $q.reject is a shortcut to create a deferred and then reject it immediately

So `$q.reject()` must be equal to

`var deferred = $q.defer(); deferred.reject()`, if not please explain the actual difference between the two.

But in my case, `$q.reject()` is working, but `deffered.reject()` is not working. Also we need to return rejected promised like `$q.reject()` but not `deferred.reject()`. I have seen examples where there is no return on `deffered.reject()`

This is the code

```
 var deferred = $q.defer();
 myService.getData()
 .then(function(response){
   deferred.notify('Just a notification');
   deferred.reject('rejected');
 })
 .then(function(response) {
   console.log('done');      
 }, function(response) {
   console.log('rejected');
 })
```

This is not working, but when I replaced `deferred.reject` with `$q.reject()`, the promise has been rejected and the control is moved to the error function of the followed then block.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it won't work in your scenario at all, you chained `.then(function (response...` onto the promise that `.getData()` has returned, not the promise that `deferred` has return. Why should this work? it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work when you use `deferred.reject` because you are not returning new rejected promise. You can use both `$q.reject()` and `deferred.reject()` you just need to return a promise in both cases.

You need to to understand that

- `$q.reject()` is rejected promise object
- `deferred.reject()` is **not** a promise, but deferred object which has rejected promise in one of its properties (namely, `$promise`).

So you can return any object or value and it will become a new promise object and will be passed to the next then block in chain. However, when you `return deferred.reject()` it will be passed as just some object (one more time, it is not a promise, but it has a promise *inside*) and next promise will get resolved successfully of course.

It will work properly with `deferred` too if you return corresponding promise:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
myService.getData()
    .then(function(response) {
        deferred.notify('Just a notification');
        deferred.reject('rejected');
        return deferred.promise;
        //return $q.reject();
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log('done');
    }, function(response) {
        console.log('rejected');
    });
```

And finally answer to you question: `$q.reject()` is a promise object with status "rejected". `deferred.reject()` is **not** a promise, but it has rejected promise object inside as `deferred.$promise`. What to use? You should use `$q.reject()`, using dummy deferred object is redundant in this case and considered bad practice, in fact it even has a name as [deferred anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns).

Comment: Great Answer! Thanks a lot. Just another question. What is actually a promise object and diferred object.

Comment: The promise object is available at deferred.promise. Got it when I logged the object.

Comment: My doubt is the diferred.promise we are returning is different from the response object we are getting in error block. What is heppening behind the scenes?

Comment: `deferred.$promise` isnt a thing

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are returning a promise.

```
function getData() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    myService.getData()
        .then(function (response) {
           deferred.resolve('Just received a notification');
        }).catch(function (err) {
           deferred.reject(err); 
        };

    return deferred.promise;
}

getData().then(function (response) {
    console.log('done');
}, function (response) {
    console.log('rejected');
});
```

Comment: I actually have this code snippet inside my controller. Could you please explain why I should return a promise.

Comment: Sure, a promise is what has the properties of `.then`, `.catch`, `.finally` so you must return the promise so it can be fulfilled. When you are doing `$q.reject` you are returning a fulfilled promise, albeit rejected.

Answer (score 0):

This is working with Q (https://github.com/kriskowal/q)

```
var def = Q.defer();
def.promise
.then(
    function(ok){
        return ok;
    },
    function(err){
        var d = Q.defer();
        d.reject(err);
        return d.promise;
    }
)
.then(
    function(ok){
        console.log('ok',ok);
    },
    function(err){
        console.log('err',err);
    }
);
def.reject('error');
```